# How to get id from sqlite using nativescript-vue

Tags: sqlite, vue.js, nativescript

I made this create table using nativescript.

```
  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS item_summary (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, item_name TEXT, purchase_date TEXT, purchase_price TEXT)")
```

And I inserted as below.

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO item_summary (item_name, purchase_date, purchase_price) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
```

And I get the result by query.

```
db.all("SELECT item_name, purchase_date, purchase_price")
```

The result that I get this object.

```
 {
    itemName: 'Mac',
    purchase_date: "20201210",
    purchase_price: "3000"
 }
```

Until this, it doesn't have any problem. But when I want to get id also, I tried like this.

```
db.all("SELECT id, item_name, purchase_date, purchase_price")
```

But in this case, I get this object.

```
{
    id: 'Mac',
    itemName: "20201210",
    purchaseDate: "3000"
 }
```

How can I correctly id in this case? Thank you for reading it.

Comment: Your select is missing table name, did you try including that?

Comment: @Manoj Yes, I did it. I just missed typing on my question.